# What is the proper syntax to allow red api access from any origin in my node express application

Tags: node.js

In my node express app I wish to allow unrestricted access to my /api/publicdata endpoint
What is the proper syntax for the allow-origin?

Comment: With [express static](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html)? `app.get('/api/data/publicdata/*, express.static('/dir/to/api/data/publicdata'))`

Comment: It will not be static. It will be a dynamo array of json objects obtained from mongo. In this form: res.json(data)

Comment: So just `app.get('/api/data/publicdata', function(req,res,n){ res.json(data) }`?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what it is.